# UIImageView Zoom/Fade animation?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview, jquery-animate

I want to make a little zoom/fade animation for when the UIImageView shows up in my view, I already have the code for the fade effect:

```
    banner.alpha = 0.0;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^{
        banner.alpha = 1.0;
    }];
```

Now I want to know if there is another easy way to combine the fade effect with a little zoom effect, like the image becoming larger and filling up the frame as it fades in? Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

you can use `CG_EXTERN CGAffineTransform CGAffineTransformMakeScale(CGFloat sx, CGFloat sy)` to do the zoom effect

such as

```
banner.alpha = 0.0;

[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^{
    banner.alpha = 1.0;
    banner.transform =CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.3,1.3);
}];
```

Comment: This is roughly it but I think Jon wants to scale from 0.0 and zoom to 1.0 in the animation.. (guessing)

Comment: @Ben yes, maybe , but the mechanism is the same ,haha ,if he want , he need to set the scale to (0,0) above the block methodv :）

Comment: @Guo Luchuan i have an imageview in UIView(subview on main view controller).when i zoomming my imageview using above code, imageview frame become outside of UIview. i also set UIview clipstobound=YES. i have to keep zooming of imageview inside UIView. please any suggestion?

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the frame

```
banner.alpha = 0;

[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0f animations:^(void){
   banner.alpha = 1.0f;
   [banner setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 748)];
}];

// With Completion
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.1f animations:^(void){
   banner.alpha = 1.0f;
   [banner setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 748)];
}completion:^(BOOL finished) {

}];
```